# Add dynamic text animation to nivo slider

Tags: css, wordpress, animation, nivo-slider

Looking for the best approach to add dynamic text animations to a nivo slider. Trying to use `animate.css`for the animations but the text is not animating. I tried adding an animation to some text outside the slider and it works fine. So not sure why it doesn't work in the slider.
Will include the nivo demo.html file I tried to modify. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<head>
<title>Nivo Slider Demo</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../themes/default/default.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../themes/light/light.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../themes/dark/dark.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../themes/bar/bar.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../nivo-slider.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../animate.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <a href="http://dev7studios.com" id="dev7link" title="Go to dev7studios">dev7studios</a>

    <div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
        <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
            <img src="images/toystory.jpg" data-thumb="images/toystory.jpg" alt="" title="#htmlcaption1" />
            <a href="http://dev7studios.com"><img src="images/up.jpg" data-thumb="images/up.jpg" alt="" title="This is an example of a caption" /></a>
            <img src="images/walle.jpg" data-thumb="images/walle.jpg" alt="" data-transition="slideInLeft" />
            <img src="images/nemo.jpg" data-thumb="images/nemo.jpg" alt="" title="#htmlcaption" />
        </div>
        <div id="htmlcaption1" class="nivo-html-caption animated bounceIn">
            <strong>This</strong> is an example of a <em>HTML</em> caption with <a href="#">a link</a>. 
        </div>
        <div id="htmlcaption" class="nivo-html-caption animated bounceIn">
            <strong>This</strong> is an example of a <em>HTML</em> caption with <a href="#">a link</a>. 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="animated bounceIn" style="position: absolute; top: 300px; left: 30px;">
        <h1 style="font: 20px;">this is a test</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.nivo.slider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#slider').nivoSlider({
        effect: 'fade'
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Is it possible to you giving us any url?

Comment: How can I include project files like stylesheets js files and images into something like jsfiddle without having to combine all the css into one file and all js into one file?

Comment: Isn't this wordpress? I'm guessing you have a domain...

Comment: Not using wordpress. Just downloaded the slider files locally from git.

Comment: Oh ok, got it! At least you can show your css file?

Comment: haven't modified any css files. I've just included animate.css into the project <head> in hopes of being able to use the css transitions in my project. I can show the nivo-slider.css file if you need me to

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89321/discussion-between-web-dev-and-gionicol).

Answer (score 0):

The abimatecss classes don't work directly, if you want to use the animatecss class you should use nivo slider's beforeChange and afterChange events, for example. OR Check My Github Project

[customize nivo slider with animated caption](https://github.com/Rubel-hossain/customize-nivo-slider)

```
 $(window).on("load", function(){

    $(".slider-wrapper").nivoSlider({

         animSpeed    : 900,
         controlNav   : false,
         nextText     : '<i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>',
         prevText     : '<i class="fa fa-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>',
         beforeChange : function(){

            $('.nivo-caption p').removeClass('animated slideInLeft').hide();
            $('.nivo-caption h2').removeClass('animated slideInRight').hide();
            $('.nivo-caption span button').removeClass('animated fadeInUp').hide();


         },
         afterChange : function(){

            $('.nivo-caption p').addClass('animated slideInLeft').show();
            $('.nivo-caption h2').addClass('animated slideInRight').show();
            $('.nivo-caption span button').addClass('animated fadeInUp').show();


         }

    });
 });
```